# Parsing errorr while getting JSON data

Tags: json, reactjs, typeerror

Supposed I have a JSON:

```
{
    "message_type": "getBallData",
    "data": [
        {
            "type": "basketball",
            "color": "red"
        }
}
```

However, I am unable to retrieve the ball type

```
import data from "../mypath/ballData.json"

const App = (props) => {


return(
  <div>
            {data && data.data.map((balldata, index) => {
              return {balldata.type}
            })}
  </div>
)}
```

I have this error:

```
Parsing error: Unexpected token, expected ","

return {balldata.type}
|               ^
```

I am not sure what is wrong. I tried `return {balldata}` and:

```
Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {balldata}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your json is invalid and you can able to correct it. It should be like

```
{
    "message_type": "getBallData",
    "data": [{
        "type": "basketball",
        "color": "red"
    }]
}
```

The error is at your return. You can put any valid javascript expression inside a curly brace. You already wrapped it while iterating through map. But again you are trying to wrap the return result.
https://reactjs.org/docs/introducing-jsx.html#embedding-expressions-in-jsx

```
const App = (props)=> {
  <div>
    { 
      data && data.data.map((balldata, index) => {
         return balldata.type;
      })
    }
  </div>
}
```

Comment: i was following this youtube page: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9C85o8jIgUU, why is it that he has to put curly braces after the return?

Comment: Yes sure, But did you noticed that, he is using the <h1> tag in return statement. It specifies that it's going to return a react element again. So he used curly braces in return statement. In your case, you are just rendering the values alone not react element.

Answer (score 0):

The error `Parsing error: Unexpected token, expected ","` would indicate the comma after `"color": "red"` should be removed, as nothing is coming after. In addition, your sample json doesn't close the array.

This should work:

```
{
    "message_type": "getBallData",
    "data": [{
        "type": "basketball",
        "color": "red"
    }]
}
```

You can also validate your JSON snippets at https://jsonlint.com/

Edit:

I've modified your example for NodeJS and it seems to work just fine:

```
data = {
    "message_type": "getBallData",
    "data": [
      {
        "type": "basketball",
        "color": "red"
      },
      {
        "type": "soccerball",
        "color": "blue"
      }
    ]
}

console.log(data.data.map((balldata, index) => {
  return balldata.type
}))


 ~  node stackoverflowww.js
[ 'basketball', 'soccerball' ]
```

So I'm confident your error is json related.

Comment: the root cause is not balldata.type, but its invalid json.

Comment: it was my typo here

Comment: So your error indicates your json is invalid, and thus the item you want to retrieve doesn't exist. Can you verify your actual json and LINT it ?

Comment: when i do console.log, i can see my data

Comment: See the updated answer on why I'm quite sure it's json related.

Comment: i cant add `data = ` in the json file. i will get this error `Expected a JSON object, array or literal.`